# How to find bold text line from image using python?

Tags: python, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/achu4.jpg)    from PIL import Image
    import pytesseract
    from pdf2image import convert_from_path
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('grey.png',gray)
binary,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imwrite('Thresh1.png',thresh1)
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 3))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
im2 = img.copy()


ROI_number = 0

for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    ROI=im2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    print(str(w),str(h))
    #cv2.putText(im2, str(h), (x,y - 10 ), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    #cv2.putText(im2, str(w), (x,y + 10 ), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    #cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number),ROI)
    cv2.rectangle(im2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),1)
    ROI_number += 1

cv2.imwrite('contours1.png',im2)
```

How to make a filter which detect the bold lines part from image Bold text line should be the output for me .Don't know to approach this thing but i have a suggestion to get that thing in order of Binary inversion Threshold covert to get the white bigger part should come from that need suggestions regarding this Problem.

Comment: How about using hough transform after the dialation to find strong lines through the line, then averaging by angle, and selecting the strongest line with angle parallel to X?

Comment: Can you tell Resources to do implementing on this code  -- Gulzar